# Minimization in single component of BSpline to extract points

Tags: evaluation, splines

I smoothed some data with a BSpline $B[t] = (x[t],y[t])$. I would like to extract certain points from this spline by their x-Values, $x_0$. The easiest way I came up with was to minimize $B[t][[1]]-x_0$ for  $t \in  [0,1]$. So for finding the parameter t at which the x value is 13.46 if have the following code:

```
data = {{9.93114`, 379022.8`}, {11.71875`, 321705.7`}, {13.46983`, 
280830.8`}, {15.625`, 243949.8`}, {18.60119`, 206915}, {21.70139`,
 179663.2`}, {24.93351`, 158942.4`}, {29.29688`, 
138396.2`}, {33.48214`, 123873.8`}};

spline = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];
tstfc[t_] := spline[t][[1]]

FindMinimum[Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46] , {x, 0}]
```

It seems like the Spline is not getting evaluated. How can I solve this? And is there a standard way to extract points from a spline? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
data = {{9.93114`, 379022.8`}, {11.71875`, 321705.7`}, {13.46983`, 
280830.8`}, {15.625`, 243949.8`}, {18.60119`, 206915}, {21.70139`, 
179663.2`}, {24.93351`, 158942.4`}, {29.29688`, 138396.2`}, {33.48214`, 
123873.8`}};

spline = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];

Clear[tstfc];
```

You need to restrict the definition of tstfc to numeric arguments. Using the symbolic result causes your problem.

```
tstfc[t_?NumericQ] := spline[t][[1]]
```

The function being minimized clearly has a local minimum:

Plot[Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46], {x, 0, 1}]

[image: Plot of function being minimized]

Plot[Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46], {x, 0.17, .173}]

[image: Close-up off minimum]

You should also constrain x.Even so, FindMinimum has some difficulty.

```
FindMinimum[{Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46], 0 <= x <= 1}, {x, .2}]
```

FindMinimum::eit: The algorithm does not converge to the tolerance of 4.806217383937354`*^-6 in 500 iterations. The best estimated solution, with feasibility residual, KKT residual, or complementary residual of {2.00154,0.757541,1.00077}, is returned. >>

{0.000010463696439089176, 
   {x -> 0.17147137220615655}}

NMinimize works better.

```
NMinimize[{Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

{1.0658141036401503*^-13, 
   {x -> 0.17147210562361115}}

Comment: @BobHanion - sorry for the vote-down. but your answer is mathematically wrong and ignores the other answers given.

Comment: The other answers agree with my result: x -> 0.171472

Comment: The other answers agree with my result: x -> 0.171472 as the value of the spline's parameter. The comments about a local minimum not existing are incorrect since the function being minimized is not the data or its spline but rather Abs[tstfc[x] - 13.46] which does have a local minimum. None of the plots plotted this argument of the FindMinimum which would show the local minimum.

Comment: Hanion - First of all, I beg your pardon for the downvote. I tried to reverse it to no avail: You must edit at least 5 characters of your answer before I can do that. A short graphical demonstration of your answer would most probably overcome my ignorance.

Comment: I added plots of function being minimized to highlight local minimum

Comment: just upvoted it - best explanation so far in this confusing thread :)

Comment: Ok, thanks! That indeed was the problem. Unfortunately the implemented minimization routines, NMinimize & FindMinimum don't seem very efficient in this case.

Answer (score 2):

If your aim is to find the parameter value t that maps to {13.46, _} in the B spline you could use:

```
data = {{9.93114`, 379022.8`}, {11.71875`, 321705.7`}, {13.46983`, 
    280830.8`}, {15.625`, 243949.8`}, {18.60119`, 206915}, {21.70139`,
     179663.2`}, {24.93351`, 158942.4`}, {29.29688`, 
    138396.2`}, {33.48214`, 123873.8`}};
bf = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];
d = Table[{bf[t][[1]], t}, {t, 0, 1, 0.01}];
ifn = Interpolation[d];
```

Then

```
ans = ifn[13.46]
```

yields:

0.171472

and the point on spline:

```
bf[ans]
```

{13.46, 283497.}

You could adjust to desired precision.

Comment: Very nice, I would assume that's the real answer :)

Comment: Hi ubpdqn, thanks for your  workaround. I would still be interested though, why my code did not work.

Comment: A problem with this approach is the variability of the precision, depending on dx/dt.

Answer (score 1):

A workaround is a Newton algorithm, if the spline is used with a Modulo 1 parameter, modelling a periodic spline function. The function to be minimized is then       `spline[t_] := Abs[spline[t][[1]] - x0];`

```
getPointNewton[x0_, splinein_, tstart_] := 
 Module[{d, t, dert, dt, spline},
  spline[t_] := Abs[spline[t][[1]] - x0];
  t = tstart;
  dt = 0.001;
  d = 1;
  While[d > 0.00000005,
   dert = (spline[t + dt] - spline[t - dt])/(2 dt);
   t = Mod[t - spline[t]/dert, 1];
  d = Abs[splinein[t][[1]] - x0];
   ];
  t
  ]
```

Edit: Works fine for this dataset, gives 0.171472 after 345 iterations, but has problems converging in more extreme data (higher derivatives/values) and close to boundaries.

The standard minimization routines in Mathematica seem to take a lot of time for convergence.

A better algorithm, which converges on the wished parameter from the left only is this one:

```
getPointLeft[x0_, spline_, tstart_] := 
 Module[{i, t, basestep, points}, i = 0;
  t = tstart;
 basestep = 1;
  points = {0};
  While[Abs[spline[t][[1]] - x0] > 0.000005, 
  If[spline[t + (1/2)^i basestep][[1]] > x0, i++, 
    t = t + (1/2)^i basestep;
    AppendTo[points, N[t]]]];
  points]

data = {{9.93114`, 379022.8`}, {11.71875`, 321705.7`}, {13.46983`, 
    280830.8`}, {15.625`, 243949.8`}, {18.60119`, 206915}, {21.70139`,
     179663.2`}, {24.93351`, 158942.4`}, {29.29688`, 
    138396.2`}, {33.48214`, 123873.8`}};

spline = BSplineFunction[data, SplineDegree -> 3];
points = getPointLeft[13.46, spline, 0]
Show[Plot[Abs[spline[t][[1]] - 13.46], {t, 0, 0.2}], 
 Graphics[{PointSize[Large], Red, 
   Point[Transpose[{points, 
      Abs[spline[#][[1]] - 13.46] & /@ points}]]}]]
```

[image: Convergence to t[x0]]

It halfs the stepsize as long as the next step would overshoot. This works well to find the next local minimum, which is fine for a case in which the dependent variable looked for is a monotonous function of the parameter t. Result:0.171472 after 33 iterations.

Comment: Again, why exactly the downvote?

Comment: I would upvote it again if you would show, with an example, that your "getPointLeft" works, yielding 0.171472

Comment: impressive, thanks. just upvoted it.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation says in its very first sentence:

> FindMinimum[f, x] searches for a local minimum in f, starting from an
>   automatically selected point.

Not ANY minimum but a LOCAL minimum.

Google it with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maxima_and_minima

As already stated yesterday, your data doesn't contain LOCAL minima and/or maxima. Your data has one GLOBAL maximum and one GLOBAL minimum which, thanks `Mathematica`, can be found as follows:

```
{First@data, Last@data}
```

Aside from this, your "getPointNewton" simply doesn't work. If it works with you, could you provide an example?

Comment: Yes my data has just two global extrema. But I am not looking for the extrema in my data, but for the extrema in Abs[Spline[data][[1]]-x0]. This has its global minimum exactly at the point where Spline[data][[1]]=x0, as Bob Hanlon showed. By the way any global maximum is also a local maximum.